# initialize character array on the fly

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to initialize a char array using pointers, on the fly.That is user giving input do not know the size of array.User keeps on giving input until return is pressed.Condition here is to:

- Use pointers to initialize
- Not to pass size of array  in advance.

Comment: Is it c or c++? If c++ - use `std::vector`

Comment: is it homework? do you need array or list ?

Comment: @amit either of the two.C or C++.

Comment: Unless you are truly constrained to using arrays, you would be far better off with `std::vector<char>`

Comment: @Andrew not homework.Just curious. :/ and it's an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a C question, how about (untested):

```
char *arr = malloc(10);
size_t size = 10, index = 0;
int ch;
while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r') {
    if (index >= size) {
        size *= 2;
        arr = realloc(arr, size); /* XXX check it first. */
    }
    arr[index++] = ch;
}
arr[index] = 0;
```

If it's really a C++ question you want [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: I would also check if ch != '\r' to be on the safe side.

Comment: no '\r' check is needed, it's ever redundant; `size` and `index` are bad var-names

Comment: There's a little trap here: if `realloc` fails, it returns a null pointer. In that case, `arr` has been overwritten, and there's no way to get at the previous data block. The data is lost, and the memory is leaked. I don't want to design the failure path here, but be aware of this problem and code for it.

Answer (score 0):

The std::string has a method `push_back` also std::vector would do the job. Still if you are REALLY forced to use a dynamic array and char pointers I would advice you to implement reallocation strategy similar to the one used in vector - double the size each time the number of elements is more then the current size.

Comment: Most implementations these days expand the storage block by 1.5 rather then 2. That wastes less space, at the cost of somewhat more frequent reallocations.